# Why rsync with jump host and sshpass not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, rsync, sshpass

I'm trying to rsync with 'sshpass' and using jump host to transform a file.

The command I am using is -

`rsync -azv -e 'sshpass -p passwordToTargetHost ssh -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p passwordToJumpHost user@JumpHost" user@TargetHost' :/path/to/target /path/to/originFile`

But I am getting -

> -bash: line 1: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1: command not found

Any help?

Comment: perhaps moving closing quote before user@TargetHost and removing spaces between it and :? `.. JumpHost" ' user@TargetHost:/path/..`

Answer (score 0):

```
env SSHPASS="JUMP_PASSWORD" \
rsync -v -a \
  -e "sshpass -d 123 ssh \
    -o ProxyCommand=\"sshpass -e ssh -W %h:%p USER@JUMP_HOST\" USER@TARGET_HOST" \
  :/remote/directory/  /local/directory/  \
123<<<TARGET_PASSWORD
```

This rsync+sshpass command will work.

`sshpass -e` obtains the password from `env SSHPASS="JUMP_PASSWORD"`

`sshpass -d 123` obtains the password from `123<<<TARGET_PASSWORD`

Since the ssh connection is defined in `rsync -e`, using the short form of `:/remote/directory/` to reference the source directory on the remote target host is all that is necessary.

I posted a similar answer on StackExchange on how to use sshpass with ssh jump hosts in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/597351/sshpass-with-ssh-j-jump-host/668489#668489